# LinkButton.OnClick Method with Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linkbutton

I'm creating a linkButton Dynamically on ASP.net. I need help on when I click the linkButton, it will store the linkbutton name to my Label1 (for example only).

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 2; ctr++)
        {
            LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.ID = "lnk" + ctr.ToString();
            link.Text = "lnkName" + ctr.ToString();
            link.Click += new EventHandler(DynamicClick);
            this.form1.Controls.Add(link);
        }
    }

//when I click the buttonLink
public void DynamicClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //label1.text will get the .text of the button that i pressed
        Label1.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in that way

```
public void DynamicClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton linkButton = sender as LinkButton;
    if (linkButton != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = linkButton.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 2; ctr++)
        {
            LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.ID = "lnk" + ctr.ToString();
            link.Text = "lnkName" + ctr.ToString();
            link.Click += delegate { Label1.Text = link.ID; };
            this.form1.Controls.Add(link);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a slight variation to Valeh's answer.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 2; ctr++)
    {
        LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
        link.ID = "lnk" + ctr.ToString();
        link.Text = "lnkName" + ctr.ToString();
        link.Click += (s, ea) =>
        {
            Label1.Text = link.Text;
        };
        this.form1.Controls.Add(link);
    }
}
```

Creating a separate method `public void DynamicClick(object sender, EventArgs e)` - especially one that is `public` - is a bad thing when it is not necessary as it breaks encapsulation. It's perfectly understandable to do so when we're working with a designer, but when we're writing the code ourselves it's a bad idea.